# Is `npx expo install` only recommended for Expo Go or is it needed for custom dev clients as well?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go, expo-build

Is it recommended to use `npx expo install [package]` when installing third-party packages with custom Expo dev clients? I know it's recommended when using Expo Go, but the docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/using-libraries/#third-party-libraries) don't really explicitly say whether or not it should be used for custom dev clients as well. The demo video [here](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/introduction/) sort of implies it, but again nothing directly mentioned.